# Oracle SQL code cannot fetch unique columns- A lot of duplicate data in the Output

Tags: oracle, oracle-fusion-apps

There are multiple updates in the salary amount, hence duplicate data with same values but different salary. My task is to remove the duplicity and only show the latest salary update data.

The main problem with code is that it is showing duplicate data.

My Code is:

```
SELECT PER_PERSON_NAMES_F.TITLE,
               PER_PERSON_NAMES_F.FIRST_NAME,
               PER_PERSON_NAMES_F.LAST_NAME,
               PER_PERSON_NAMES_F.FULL_NAME,
              PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F.PERSON_NUMBER,
              PER_NATIONAL_IDENTIFIERS.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER,
             PER_NATIONAL_IDENTIFIERS.LEGISLATION_CODE,
             to_char(PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY') AS EFFECTIVE_START_DATE,
             to_char(PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY') AS EFFECTIVE_END_DATE,
             to_char(PER_PERSONS.DATE_OF_BIRTH,'DD-MM-YYYY') AS DOB,
             PER_ALL_ASSIGNMENTS_M.ASSIGNMENT_TYPE,
             PER_EMAIL_ADDRESSES.EMAIL_ADDRESS,
            PER_PHONES.PHONE_NUMBER
FROM PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F JOIN PER_PERSONS ON PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F.PERSON_ID=PER_PERSONS.PERSON_ID JOIN PER_PERSON_NAMES_F ON 
PER_PERSONS.PERSON_ID=PER_PERSON_NAMES_F.PERSON_ID JOIN PER_ALL_ASSIGNMENTS_M ON
PER_PERSON_NAMES_F.PERSON_ID=PER_ALL_ASSIGNMENTS_M.PERSON_ID JOIN PER_NATIONAL_IDENTIFIERS ON 
PER_ALL_ASSIGNMENTS_M.PERSON_ID=PER_NATIONAL_IDENTIFIERS.PERSON_ID JOIN PER_EMAIL_ADDRESSES ON 
PER_NATIONAL_IDENTIFIERS.PERSON_ID=PER_EMAIL_ADDRESSES.PERSON_ID JOIN 
(
   SELECT PERSON_ID,TRUNC(SALARY_AMOUNT,2) AS SALARY,max(LAST_UPDATE_DATE) as SALARY_UPDATE_DATE
    FROM CMP_SALARY
    GROUP BY PERSON_ID
)  CMP_SALARY ON
PER_EMAIL_ADDRESSES.PERSON_ID=CMP_SALARY.PERSON_ID JOIN PER_PHONES ON CMP_SALARY.PERSON_ID = PER_PHONES.PERSON_ID
AND PER_NATIONAL_IDENTIFIERS.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER IN (
SELECT DISTINCT NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER FROM PER_NATIONAL_IDENTIFIERS)
ORDER BY PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F.PERSON_NUMBER
```

How to remove duplicity in this code?

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for a **minimal** example that replicates the problem of duplicate data.; and the expected output for that sample data. You probably have the problem because you are using `JOIN` and have a one-to-many relationships rather than one-to-one relationships and that is causing the data to be duplicated across those joined rows; however, we cannot confirm that because you have not provided us with any way of replicating the problem.

Comment: The statement in your question will not execute as you `GROUP BY person_id` but return `salary_amount` without either aggregating or including it in the `GROUP BY` clause. Instead it will return a `Not a Group By Expression` exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT PERSON_ID,TRUNC(SALARY_AMOUNT,2) AS SALARY,LAST_UPDATE_DATE as SALARY_UPDATE_DATE
FROM CMP_SALARY
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PERSON_ID ORDER BY LAST_UPDATE_DATE DESC) = 1


OR 

SELECT PERSON_ID,SALARY,SALARY_UPDATE_DATE FROM(
SELECT PERSON_ID,TRUNC(SALARY_AMOUNT,2) AS SALARY,LAST_UPDATE_DATE AS SALARY_UPDATE_DATE,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PERSON_ID ORDER BY LAST_UPDATE_DATE DESC) AS row_num
FROM CMP_SALARY)
WHERE row_num = 1;
```

You may try the above to dedup the data , second solution if qualify is not supported.

Comment: Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Comment: Can you please run the statement individually first and check if it's giving the expected results , and then add it to the main query .

Comment: Same error while running both of them individually

Comment: Oracle does not support the `QUALIFY` keyword - see the [`SELECT` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF01702). The second query should work (although if the OP is copy-pasting it into their query then they don't want to include the final `;` statement terminator).

Comment: All the solutions provided would handle the duplicate records from CMP_SALARY Table. But as MT0 mentioned, one of the joins seem to have one-to-many relationship. You should try to remove table joins one by one and see which table is causing the duplicate and then try to fix the join condition to get a unique record.

Answer (score 0):

If you pre-calculate salaries (using `row_number` function), then see marked part of code:

```
  SELECT per_person_names_f.title,
         per_person_names_f.first_name,
         per_person_names_f.last_name,
         per_person_names_f.full_name,
         per_all_people_f.person_number,
         per_national_identifiers.national_identifier_number,
         per_national_identifiers.legislation_code,
         TO_CHAR (per_all_people_f.effective_start_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY')
            AS effective_start_date,
         TO_CHAR (per_all_people_f.effective_end_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY')
            AS effective_end_date,
         TO_CHAR (per_persons.date_of_birth, 'DD-MM-YYYY')
            AS dob,
         per_all_assignments_m.assignment_type,
         per_email_addresses.email_address,
         per_phones.phone_number
    FROM per_all_people_f
         JOIN per_persons ON per_all_people_f.person_id = per_persons.person_id
         JOIN per_person_names_f ON per_persons.person_id = per_person_names_f.person_id
         JOIN per_all_assignments_m
            ON per_person_names_f.person_id = per_all_assignments_m.person_id
         JOIN per_national_identifiers
            ON per_all_assignments_m.person_id = per_national_identifiers.person_id
         JOIN per_email_addresses
            ON per_national_identifiers.person_id = per_email_addresses.person_id
         JOIN
-- change begins here ...
         (SELECT x.person_id,
                 TRUNC (x.salary_amount, 2) AS salary,
                 x.last_update_date AS salary_update_date
            FROM (SELECT person_id,
                         salary_amount,
                         last_update_date,
                         ROW_NUMBER ()
                            OVER (PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY last_update_date DESC) rn_sal
                    FROM cmp_salary
                 ) x
           WHERE x.rn_sal = 1
         ) cmp_salary
-- ... and ends here
            ON per_email_addresses.person_id = cmp_salary.person_id
         JOIN per_phones
            ON     cmp_salary.person_id = per_phones.person_id
               AND per_national_identifiers.national_identifier_number IN
                      (SELECT DISTINCT national_identifier_number
                         FROM per_national_identifiers)
ORDER BY per_all_people_f.person_number
```

Comment: Error: Not a Group By Expression

Comment: Right, my bad, sorry. Though, your current query suffers from the same error as you didn't group by TRUNC(SALARY_AMOUNT,2) either. I fixed code, have a look.

Comment: This would get the earliest `last_update_date` but the OP was after the latest `last_update_date`. You need to use `PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY last_update_date DESC` (like the other two answers).

Comment: But of course! DESC it is, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MAX(salary) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY last_update_date)` to get the maximum salary for the latest update date:

```sql
SELECT n.TITLE,
       n.FIRST_NAME,
       n.LAST_NAME,
       n.FULL_NAME,
       ap.PERSON_NUMBER,
       ni.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER,
       ni.LEGISLATION_CODE,
       to_char(ap.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY') AS EFFECTIVE_START_DATE,
       to_char(ap.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY') AS EFFECTIVE_END_DATE,
       to_char(p.DATE_OF_BIRTH,'DD-MM-YYYY') AS DOB,
       aa.ASSIGNMENT_TYPE,
       e.EMAIL_ADDRESS,
       ph.PHONE_NUMBER
FROM   PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F ap
       JOIN PER_PERSONS p               ON ap.PERSON_ID = p.PERSON_ID
       JOIN PER_PERSON_NAMES_F n        ON ap.PERSON_ID = n.PERSON_ID
       JOIN PER_ALL_ASSIGNMENTS_M aa    ON ap.PERSON_ID = a.PERSON_ID
       JOIN PER_NATIONAL_IDENTIFIERS ni ON ap.PERSON_ID = ni.PERSON_ID
       JOIN PER_EMAIL_ADDRESSES e       ON ap.PERSON_ID = e.PERSON_ID
       JOIN (
         SELECT PERSON_ID,
                TRUNC(
                  MAX(SALARY_AMOUNT) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY last_update_date),
                  2
                ) AS SALARY,
                max(LAST_UPDATE_DATE) as SALARY_UPDATE_DATE
         FROM   CMP_SALARY
         GROUP BY PERSON_ID
      ) s                               ON ap.PERSON_ID = s.PERSON_ID
      JOIN PER_PHONES ph                ON ap.PERSON_ID = ph.PERSON_ID
ORDER BY
      ap.PERSON_NUMBER
```

or, use the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function (without using `GROUP BY`):

```sql
SELECT n.TITLE,
       n.FIRST_NAME,
       n.LAST_NAME,
       n.FULL_NAME,
       ap.PERSON_NUMBER,
       ni.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER,
       ni.LEGISLATION_CODE,
       to_char(ap.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY') AS EFFECTIVE_START_DATE,
       to_char(ap.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY') AS EFFECTIVE_END_DATE,
       to_char(p.DATE_OF_BIRTH,'DD-MM-YYYY') AS DOB,
       aa.ASSIGNMENT_TYPE,
       e.EMAIL_ADDRESS,
       ph.PHONE_NUMBER
FROM   PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F ap
       JOIN PER_PERSONS p               ON ap.PERSON_ID = p.PERSON_ID
       JOIN PER_PERSON_NAMES_F n        ON ap.PERSON_ID = n.PERSON_ID
       JOIN PER_ALL_ASSIGNMENTS_M aa    ON ap.PERSON_ID = a.PERSON_ID
       JOIN PER_NATIONAL_IDENTIFIERS ni ON ap.PERSON_ID = ni.PERSON_ID
       JOIN PER_EMAIL_ADDRESSES e       ON ap.PERSON_ID = e.PERSON_ID
       JOIN (
         SELECT PERSON_ID,
                SALARY_AMOUNT AS SALARY,
                LAST_UPDATE_DATE as SALARY_UPDATE_DATE,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                  PARTITION BY person_id
                  ORDER BY last_update_date DESC, salary_amount DESC
                ) AS rn
         FROM   CMP_SALARY
      ) s                               ON  ap.PERSON_ID = s.PERSON_ID
                                        AND s.rn = 1
      JOIN PER_PHONES ph                ON ap.PERSON_ID = ph.PERSON_ID
ORDER BY
      ap.PERSON_NUMBER
```

Comment: Replicate data still visible

Comment: @Seeker You are using lots of `JOIN`s if each person has one row in the `PER_PERSONS` table but then there are multiple rows for one of those people in the other table then you are creating a one-to-many join and you will get many rows of output for that person - that is what it means to `JOIN` tables. If you want to only get a single row per person then you sill need to make sure that **ALL** the tables you join to only return a single row and then all the joins will be one-to-one. You have not provided a [MRE] so we can't replicate your issue of duplicated data.